# Dealing with long requests in Unicorn + Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, node.js, nginx, unicorn

We have a Rails app that we run on Unicorn (2 workers) and nginx. We want to integrate a 3rd party API where processing of a single request takes between 1 and 20 seconds. If we simply create a new controller that proxies to that service the entire app suffers, because it takes only 2 people to make a request to that service via our API and for 20 seconds the rest of the users can't access the rest of our app.

We're thinking about 2 solutions.

1. Create a separate node.js server that will do all of the requests to the 3rd party API. We would only use Rails for authentication/authorization in this case, and we would redirect the requests to node via nginx using X-Accel-Redirect header (as described here http://blog.bitbucket.org/2012/08/24/segregating-services/)
2. Replace Unicorn with Thin or Rainbow! and keep proxying in our Rails app, which could then, presumably, allow us to handle many more concurrent connections.

Which solution might we be better off? Or is there something else we could do.

I personally feel that nodes even-loop is better suited for the job here, because in option 2 we would still be blocking many threads and waiting for HTTP requests to finish and in option 1, we could be doing more requests while waiting for the slow ones to finish.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to checkout puma if you are changing webservers - http://puma.io/ - or if you background the work, delayed job might be the easiest? Node might be better, i have 0 experience with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've been using the `X-Accel-Redirect` solution in production for a while now and it's working great.

In nginx config under server, we have entries for external services (written in node.js in our case), e.g.

```
server {
  ...
  location ^~ /some-service {
    internal;
    rewrite ^/some-service/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://location-of-some-service:5000;
  }
}
```

In rails we authenticate and authorize the requests and when we want to pass it to some other service, in the controller we do something like

```
headers['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '/some-service'
render :nothing => true
```

Now, rails is done with processing the request and hands it back to nginx. Nginx sees the `x-accel-redirect` header and replays the request to the new url - `/some-service` which we configured to proxy to our node.js service. Unicorn and rails can now process new requests even if node.js+nginx is still processing that original request.

This way we're using Rails as our main entry point and gatekeeper of our application - that's where authentication and authorization happens. But we were able to move a lot of functionality into these smaller, standalone node.js services when that's more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EventMachine` in your existing Rails app which would mean much less re-writing. Instead of making a `net/http` request to the API, you would make a `EM::HttpRequest` request to the API and add a callback. This is similar to node.js option but does not require a special server IMO.

Comment: but doesn't that mean that the Unicorn worker is still blocked, waiting for EM to callback until it can return the response to the browser?

Comment: I wouldn't think so. The request to the third party Api will be inside a Em.run block and won't block the main thread or process. I will put up an example later but do give it a try.

Comment: Thin is written using Eventmachine and so, if unicorn gives you trouble with EM::HTTP, replace it with Thin. Rainbows! too has a support for Eventmachine.

Comment: See I think if you just keep Unicorn and try to use EM, it won't help in anyway, because it will still be able to process only 2 concurrent requests. Even if EM will be doing an async HTTP request, my unicorn process has to block and wait for EM to finish the request so that it can respond with results to the browser. Now if I switch to a different server, e.g. Puma or Thin, I can now handle many more concurrent connections by using threads, but EM still doesn't help in any way, because those threads will have to sit there and wait for EM response before they can respond to the browser.

Comment: I'm facing something similar right now with a Rails 3 app. Did you have any resolution?

Comment: I wrote up our solution in more detail above